# Make a auto run file with free dos

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am trying to write a small diagnostic menu using open source software. I was thinking that I would make a bootable dos cd from using freedos then making an autorun batch file as my menu to execute other utilities. How would I link the freedos with a batch to autorun my batch file ? Any information or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you're looking to create an `AUTOEXEC.BAT` file.  That batch file will run automatically at boot time.

Check [the docs](http://help.fdos.org/en/hhstndrd/batch/autoexec.htm) for details.

Comment: Just what I am looking for

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Make sure you accept the answer if you find it's useful. :-)